# Query time and write to a label

Tags: c#, .net, gtk, monodevelop

Query time and write to a label.

How to query the time and write to a label. 
In Windows is it easy:

```
Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```

How can this be done in MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what kind of application you're building, it should be done exactly the same way.